# In JavaScript ES8 async/await, how to unwait those I don't care about?

Tags: javascript, async-await

ES8 async/await made JS developer's life much easier, I'm converting my old code to use it, there is one case, some actions I don't care about the result, just like I just want to fire the event, don't want to wait to see its result, how to deal with this?

Say:

```
const doMyTasks = () => {
   try {
      //Do first task
      let prom_t1 = util.promisify(myUpdateRecord);
      let res_rec = await prom_t1();
      //Do the second task
      let prom_t2 = util.promisity(shootNotificationEmails);
      //currently
      await prom_t2(res_rec);
      //Do the third task
      let prom_t3 = util.promisfy(restHouseKeep);
      await prom_t3();

   } catch(error) {
     console.log(`What hell is going on? ${error.message} [stack: ${error.stack}]`);
   }
};
```

For the second task, I don't want to wait for the result, just want to shoot the event to trig email notification processing, skip to the third task immediately, except call shotNotificationEmails directly w/o promisify, is there any more elegant way in ES8 for this?

Thanks.  :)

Comment: You mean other than simply calling `shootNotificationEmails()`?

Comment: it seems to me that your code does this in a good way! so what do you exactly want ?

Comment: just dont put an `await`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is call `prom_t2(res_rec)` without using `await`! This will allow `doMyTasks` to continue running without waiting for `prom_t2` to complete.

Note one side-effect of this pattern is that that any errors thrown by `prom_t2` will not be caught in your `try`/`catch`, but will rather surface as global unhandled errors.